# How does length of array in javascript decided? Why is the length of array object person is 1 in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var person = [];
person.name = "Mr. White";
person.job= "Engineer";
person.push(5);
```

What is the answer of person.length and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have somewhat peculiar behavior with regards to their `.length` property. As [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects) describes it:

> Every Array object has a non-configurable "length" property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 232. **The value of the "length" property is numerically greater than the name of every own property whose name is an array index**; whenever an own property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant. Specifically, whenever an own property is added whose name is an array index, the value of the "length" property is changed

An "array index" is a whole number between 0 and `2 ** 32 - 1`.

Of the properties on the `person` array, the highest (and only) array index property is that of the `5` you pushed, which is at index 0.

```js
var person = [];
person.name = "Mr. White";
person.job= "Engineer";
person.push(5);

console.log(person[0]); // 5
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty(0)); // true
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty(1)); // false
// so the highest array index property that exists is 0
```

So, the length of the array is one plus that index: `0 + 1`, or `1`.

The `name` and `job` properties are not array indicies, so they are completely ignored when identifying the `length`.